# Set scss variable's value at runtime or startup

Tags: javascript, css, sass

I have a `.scss` file with variables setted and with those variables I can calculate other values.

I want to change their values at runtime or pass them other values on starts.
there is a way to to this?

e.g.: in a file I have `$myWidth: 500px`. This value must be different sometimes, 
and I want to set in some way this value without create a different `.scss` file

Comment: I don't think it's possible. I also don't understand this wasy. SASS is only for simplifying writing CSS and final output will be CSS files

Answer (score 1):

SASS is what we call a **pre**processor. That means there is no *real time* when writing sass.

What you can do is produce css code for all your possible use cases and enable disable it (may it via changing a class name or importing a different css file) at will.

For example lets say you want to change the width of a div based on the number of siblings that preceded it.

```
@for $i from 0 through 15 {
  .container div:nth-child($i) {width: #{$i * 50}px;}
}
```

Answer (score -1):

That means your scss is compiled for every request, slowing down your machine and increasing the time it takes for your response to be sent.

If you want to change things at runtime you can include another scss file with overrides when needed.

Comment: That's exactly what the OP asked how to _avoid_ doing... this answer is not constructive. Also, the first part of your comment is inaccurate, since sass doesn't run per request, it runs during build time. So no, it wouldn't have an impact on load times.